# Web Publish .net core website using MSBuild

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild

I'm trying to Web Publish a .zip created by `dotnet publish` from Azure DevOps. There's a WinRM Web Publish task but it's unsatisfactory because it uses port 5986 and requires a self-signed certificate on the target server, which only lasts for one year.

Is it possible to use MSBuild instead such that it doesn't attempt a build and only does a publish?

I figure this should be possible because I can use Web Publish from Visual Studio and it doesn't use port 5986.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSBuild depends on or uses MSDeploy, which handles Web Publish. (I could see this from the summary of the publish profile in Visual Studio.)

There's an Azure DevOps task for this here...

https://github.com/rschiefer/MSDeployAllTheThings/tree/master/Tasks/MSDeployPackageSync

Answer (score 0):

Do publish without build, you can use `dotnet publish --no-build`. You can check the additional [options here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21). If you need to change the port, you can change it from the Program.cs file with this:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseUrls("http://localhost:5054")
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
```

Comment: Dotnet publish doesn’t build already. And the port number is for Web Publish not the website itself.